# How to check that an array contains a particular value in Scala 2.8?

Tags: arrays, scala

I've got an array A of D unique (int, int) tuples.

I need to know if the array contains (X, Y) value.

Am I to implement a search algorithm myself or there is a standard function for this in Scala 2.8? I've looked at [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html) but couldn't find anything of such there.

Comment: Did you searched doc? https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#contains[A1%3E:A](elem:A1):Boolean

Answer (score 50, accepted):

That seems easy (unless I'm missing something):

```
scala> val A = Array((1,2),(3,4))
A: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,2), (3,4))

scala> A contains (1,2)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> A contains (5,6)
res1: Boolean = false
```

I think the api calls you're looking for is in [ArrayLike](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayLike.html).

Comment: It would be nice if Eclipse could find methods available via implicit conversion. I ended up here because it didn't show up in the ctrl+space list, and I was floored that it wasn't a standard method.

Answer (score 6):

I found this nice way of doing

```
scala> var personArray = Array(("Alice", 1), ("Bob", 2), ("Carol", 3))
personArray: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((Alice,1), (Bob,2), (Carol,3))

scala> personArray.find(_ == ("Alice", 1))
res25: Option[(String, Int)] = Some((Alice,1))

scala> personArray.find(_ == ("Alic", 1))
res26: Option[(String, Int)] = None

scala> personArray.find(_ == ("Alic", 1)).getOrElse(("David", 1))
res27: (String, Int) = (David,1)
```